# What FOSS software do you like to use to build intrusion detection stacks?

Tags: ids

Start-ups and organizations with limited budgets that are security conscious are often encouraged to deploy intrusion detection stacks.  Given that ***prevention will always fail***, intrusion detection stacks are often vital to learn why defenses failed.

I am a fan of the following intrusion stack covering the app layer, system layer, and network layer:

> system:  [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/)
>   application:  [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/apache/)
>   network:  [FlowMatrix](http://www.akmalabs.com/flowmatrix.php)  (i cheated, this one is not FOSS, but it's free!)

What are your favorite intrusion (FOSS or free) stacks?

Comment: ModSecurity is more of a WAF (web application firewall) than IDS (though of course you can set it to log instead of block...) Not familiar with the other ones.

Comment: I disagree: most of the installations I've seen ModSec deployed it is used to enhance visibility (i.e. logging & intrusion detection).  I use it the same way.  Ivan Ristiæ (original author of ModSecurity https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/index.html) actually says in his book:  “Other times I will call it an HTTP intrusion detection tool, because I think that name better describes what ModSecurity does.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- http://www.owasp.org/index.php/The_ESAPI_Web_Application_Firewall_%28ESAPI_WAF%29
- http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AppSensor_Project
- http://qosient.com/argus/
- http://ourmon.sourceforge.net

Comment: Argus is a great tool.  We use it all the time as a supplementary data source for forensics examinations and incident handling.

Answer (score 5):

Snort is an excellent IDS with a long track record.  I have deployed slightly over a dozen sensors at my organization, and am continually adding more to the mix. Snort's biggest downfall is the fact that current versions are single-threaded, though that will be changing with the upcoming version 3 release.  Combined with the [Emerging Threats](http://www.emergingthreats.net/) rules, I have been extremely impressed with the product.

The full platform consists of:

- [Snort](http://www.snort.org/)
- [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) (for system management and rule dissimination)
- [Oinkmaster](http://oinkmaster.sourceforge.net/) (for rule updates and management)
- [Cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/) (for provisioning)
- RedHat

All logging is aggregated using RSA enVision, though Splunk should it handle it fine.

Answer (score 2):

The Bro IDS http://www.bro-ids.org/ which has been funded by the National Science Foundation's Strategic Technologies for the Internet program, DOE, DEC, and other research groups.  It has it's own event-driven system and can also import Snort rules for added signature based detection.